# Process gets stuck on futex_wait_queue_me()

Tags: 11.10, java

I have a process that uses Groovy+Java and works fine on a windows machine, but on Ubuntu 11.10 it hangs every a couple of minutes for a few minutes (!!) when I look at the resource monitor I see there is no CPU or Memory usage and the process is in futex_wait_queue_me() mode. The process is a simple loop feeding data to a DB (again, works fine on windows).
How to resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the thread

futex_wait_queue_me hanging Firefox under Ubuntu, here is how I solved it.

As someone mentioned turning off asst. technology is suppose to work for the bug, but, for many it does not.  It is because of a feature still turned on by default from the newer v11.04 download.

Go to
assistive tech.
keyboard access
keyboard pref
acc.
keyboard acc. audio feedback
(unclick) beep when acc. features are turned on/off.

Do a new reboot of the system. Problem fixed.

Now, you will see that gvfs-fuse-daemon still has the futex_wait_queue_me listed under channel, but, Firefox is no longer hanging or crashing.

In the FWIW category, I noticed it mostly crashed with pop-ups blocked when the browser went to fetch whatever from google analatics, so, there may be something left over from Chrome's tracking acting as a bug., I don't know. I just started using Ubuntu so I can say without a doubt, I am not an expert. Also, it improved the playback of videos under VCT too where the video went blank.  This probably has to do with the flash player.

The other thing that might be common are people using the Sis630et chip set on older Pentium 4/Celeron systems.

Posting this here because I don't know how to effectively get the word out to save people the hassle, but, this came up near the top of my search for a solution and I wanted to help better great software.